# Given a correlation between A and B, can I calculate bounds on the correlation between A and C plus A and B?

Tags: statistics, correlation

Lets say I have three variables, A, B, and C. I can of course calculate the correlation between any of them (and have these numbers). However what I'm interested in is if there's a bound on the correlation of A and C plus B and C, $r_{A,C}$ + $r_{B,C}$, given $r_{A,B}$. Intuitively it seems like there should be one, but I'm not sure. Does anyone know?

Alternatively, could we find a bound for $r_{A,C}$ $\cdot $ $r_{B,C}$?

Comment: What do you mean by correlation? There's a technical term in statistics, but it kind of looks like you might mean something more general.

Comment: Hello, I specifically mean the Pearson correlation coefficient.